# After registration password : Your password is not correct

Tags: users, emails

Once i registered my account with email and username, mail from account settings is getting. In that mail Password : Your password is displaying. If i used that password, it shows incorrect. I check ed in my account settings, its shows
username: [user:name]
password: Your password
What i need to change to get the correct password in mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this module : [Registration Password Token](https://drupal.org/project/rpt). It will provide the user register password as a token.

> This small module provides token [user:password] during user registration. Site administrator allowed to customize the text of the e-mail that is sent to the user after registration.